# Decompose a floating-point number into its integral and fractional part

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, integer, precision

I am implementing a fractional delay line algorithm.
One of the tasks involved is the decomposition of a floating-point value into its integral and fractional part. 
I know there are a lot of posts about this topic on SO and I probably read most of them.
However I haven’t found one post that deals with the specifics of this scenario.

- The algorithm must be using 64-bit floating-point values.
- Input floating-point values are guaranteed to always be positive. (delay times cannot be negative)
- The output integer part has to be represented by an integer datatype.
- The integer datatype must have enough bits so that the double-to-integer conversion occurs without the risk of overflowing.
- Issues resulting from floating-point values lacking an exact internal representation must be avoided.
  (i.e. 9223372036854775809.0 might be internally represented as 9223372036854775808.9999998 and when cast to integer it erroneously becomes 9223372036854775808)
- The implementation should work regardless of rounding mode or compiler optimization settings.

So I wrote a function:

```
 double my_modf(double x, int64_t *intPartOut);
```

As you can see its signature is similar to the modf() function in the C standard library.

The first implementation I came up with is:

```
double my_modf(double x, int64_t *intPartOut)
{
    double y;
    double fracPart = modf(x, &y);
    *intPartOut = (int64_t)y;
    return fracPart;
}
```

I have also been experimenting with this implementation which - at least on my machine - runs faster than the previous, however I doubt its robustness.

```
double my_modf(double x, int64_t *intPartOut)
{
    int64_t y = (int64_t)x;
    *intPartOut = y;
    return x - y;
}
```

...and this is my latest attempt:

```
double my_modf(double x, int64_t *intPartOut)
{
    *intPartOut = llround(x);
    return x - floor(x);
}
```

I can't make up my mind as to which implementation would be best to use, or if there are other implementations that I haven't considered that would better accomplish the following goals.
I am looking for the (1) most robust and (2) most efficient implementation to decompose a floating-point number into its integral and fractional part, keeping into consideration the list of points mentioned above.

Comment: Wrong premise. 11 is exact, as are all other integers within the mantissa precision.

Comment: Re “The integer datatype must have enough bits so that the double-to-integer conversion occurs without the risk of overflowing”: A typical `double` can represent values up to almost 2^1024. Do you have 1024-integer types? Or do you have some other bound on the magnitude?

Comment: Re “11.0 might be internally represented as 10.99999999999999”: No, 11 is represented internally as 11. It is possible you might have a result of some calculations that would have, if performed with real-number arithmetic, produced 11 but, having been calculated with floating-point arithmetic, produced a number different from 11, such as 10.9999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875. But by the time this number is passed to `my_modf`, it is 10.9999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875 and there is no indication it would have been 11 in an alternative universe…

Comment: … Which means that, unless you have some side-channel information about the number, it is impossible for `my_modf` to produce 11 when 10.9999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875 “would have been” 11 and to produce 10 when it “would have been” a number less than 11. E.g., if you know that all the numbers passed to `my_modf` would be, if they had been calculated with real-number arithmetic, multiples of 1/60, then `my_modf` can round all its inputs to account for that.

Comment: Once these issues are dealt with, the differences in the code you show are minimal. Partitioning a floating-point number into integer and fractional parts is largely straightforward and can be done without introducing new error.

Comment: @Luigi: if your number is 10.999999999, then what you actually want to do is to truncate it, i.e. you want to cast it and get 10, because the fractional part will be 0.999999999

Comment: I apologize for my inaccurate premise. I should have said 9223372036854775809.0 and not 11.0. Now 9223372036854775809.0 cannot be exactly represented by a 64-bit floating-point data type and its internal representation is an approximation. I fixed it in the question.

Comment: Correct conversion of an integer to a floating-point format never produces a non-integer. Converting “9223372036854775809” to a floating-point format, or even performing any calculation that produces a number in IEEE-754 binary64 format that is near 9223372036854775809 will never produce a non-integer. The two nearest values representable in IEEE-754 binary64 are 9223372036854775808 and 9223372036854775810. However, if either of these is passed to `my_modf`, there is no way for it to know that 9223372036854775809 was desired.

Comment: You need to describe the problem more accurately and specifically. It is impossible to expect that the integer part of a IEEE-754 binary64 can be represented in a binary integer type unless you have a 2048-bit integer type or you have some other bound on what the magnitude can be. Do you have a 2048-bit integer type? Do you have a bound on what the maximum magnitude passed to `my_modf` will be?

Comment: Where is the number coming from? What calculations were performed to produce it? What errors might it contain?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: My maximum magnitude bound is 2^63 - 1: the positive limit for a signed 64-bit integer.

Comment: "9223372036854775809.0 might be internally represented as 9223372036854775808.9999998" is simply wrong. It's not and can't be.

Comment: Use first one.  No gimmicks - clean code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the maximum value of the integer part of the floating-point input `x` is 2<sup>63</sup>−1 and that `x` is non-negative, then both:

```
double my_modf(double x, int64_t *intPartOut)
{
    double y;
    double fracPart = modf(x, &y);
    *intPartOut = y;
    return fracPart;
}
```

and:

```
double my_modf(double x, int64_t *intPartOut)
{
    int64_t y = x;
    *intPartOut = y;
    return x - y;
}
```

will correctly return the integer part in `intPartOut` and the fractional part in the return value regardless of rounding mode.

[GCC 9.2 for x86_64 does a better job optimizing the latter version](https://godbolt.org/z/xDEAkS), and so does Apple Clang 11.0.0.

`llround` will not return the integer part as desired because it rounds to the nearest integer rather than truncating.

Issues about `x` containing errors cannot be resolved with the information provided in the question. The routines shown above have no error; they return exactly the integer and fractional parts of their input.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer** after reading your comment below.

If you are already sure the values are within [0, 2^63-1] then a simple cast will be faster than `llround()` since this function may also check for overflow (on my system, the manual page states so, however the C standard does not require it).

On my machine for example (x86-64 Nehalem) casting is a single instruction (`cvttsd2si`) and `llround()` is obviously more than one.

> Am I guaranteed to get the right result with a simple cast (truncation) or is it safer to round?

Depends on what you mean with "right". If the value in the `double` can be correctly represented by an `int64_t`, then sure you're going to get exactly the same value. However, if the value cannot be precisely represented by the `double` then truncation is automatically performed when casting. If you want to round the value in a different way that's another story and you'll have to use one of [`ceil()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ceil), [`floor()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/floor) or [`round()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/round).

If you also are sure that no values will be +/- Infinity or NaN (and in that case you can use `-Ofast`), then your second implementation should be the fastest if you want truncation, while the third should be the fastest if you want to `floor()` the value.

Comment: My maximum magnitude bound is 2^63 - 1. In your answer you mentioned both modf() and llround(). modf() is obviously used to break the value into integer and fractional part, both represented in floating-point format. Should I also use llround() to convert the floating-point integer part to an integer data type, or can I simply use casting? Am I guaranteed to get the right result with a simple cast (truncation) or is it safer to round?

Comment: @LuigiCastelli in that case then you can use the two functions without a problem. `llround()` can be helpful for identifying domain errors (i.e. if the `double` to be converted is too large, it does not result in undefined behavior, and it sets `errno` appropriately), but if you are already sure the data is within [0, 2^63-1] then a simple cast will be faster.

Comment: "llround() since this function also checks for overflow."  --> That functionality is not specified by C.  The function may check for overflow - might not.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica well, I read on the man page: `If  x  is  a NaN or an infinity, or the rounded value is too large to be stored in a long (long long in the case of the ll* functions), then a domain error occurs, and the return value is unspecified. The following errors can occur: Domain error: x is a NaN or infinite, or the rounded value is too large. An invalid floating-point exception (FE_INVALID) is raised.`

Comment: The C specs says "If the rounded value is
outside the range of the return type, the numeric result is unspecified and a domain error or range error may occur."  C17/18dr § 7.12.9.7 2  When "man pages" and the C spec differ, I go with the C spec.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica huh, so that "may" occur is the culprit here. I see, thank you!